# multi-threading - How to control print statements from function during thread calls in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am using ThreadPoolExecuter for parallel execution of a function which prints statements and executes the sql. I would like to manage the print statements from the function. Eg

```
def Func(host,sql):
   print ('Executing for %s ' %host)
   SQL = Execute(host,SQL) -- connecting to DB
   print SQL

main():
sql = 'show databases;'

hostList = ['abc.com','def.com','ghi.com','jkl.com']
 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     future = [executor.submit(Func,acct ,host,sql) for host in hostList]
```

Here for 4 items in hostList it executes the thread and executes the function Func in parallel but prints results like below

```
Executing for abc.com
Executing for def.com
Executing for ghi.com
Executing for jkl.com

then 
SQL output 1
SQL output 2
SQL output 3
SQL output 4
```

How I would like the function to print is like below

```
Executing for abc.com
 SQL output 1

Executing for def.com
 SQL output 1

Executing for ghi.com
 SQL output 1

Executing for jkl.com
 SQL output 1
```

Comment: If you waited for the output to be like this would you effectively no longer be multiprocessing? Alternatively are you just looking to group your prints together not reflecting the actual timing of the executions?

Comment: Yes I am looking to group my prints together.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to group your print statements together without reflecting the pause required to execute then you can do the following. Note that if the ONLY thing you are doing is a single print statement then you likely don't need the lock.

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import random
import time

def Func(account, host, sql, lock):
    seconds = random.randint(1, 10)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    result = "Result of executing \"{}\" took {} seconds".format(sql, seconds)

    ## -------------------------------
    ## Probably don't need to lock if you combine these into one statement
    ## -------------------------------
    with lock:
        print('Executing for %s ' % host)
        print("\t{}\n".format(result))
    ## -------------------------------

lock = threading.Lock()
hostList = ['abc.com','def.com','ghi.com','jkl.com']
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = [executor.submit(Func, "acct" , host, "somesql", lock) for host in hostList]
```

Comment: How come a "multiprocessing" lock will work with a ThreadPool? Just use a normal threading.Lock

Comment: Oops, you are correct. I though the example was ProcessPoolExecutor not ThreadPoolExecutor. I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks JonSg and appreciate both for the help.